Gorenstein k-algebra
What is relation between gorenstein k-algebra and a system of parameters of a Cohen-Macaulay k-algebra
Is that true?
a gorenstein k-algebra is the quotient of a Cohen-Macaulay k-algebra over a system of it's parameters
K is an infinite field
